# Force application in portrait mode.(including hardware keyboard)

Tags: android, launcher, portrait

I am trying to modify a launcher to force it in portrait mode.
I added 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation
in activity

But still problem is hardware keyboard, it force it to go in landscape mode.
How can i lock the launcher to be in portrait mode even when hardware keyboard is on.

Comment: What do you mean? If you force an `Activity` into portrait, but adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` the given `Activity` will be in `portrait mode`.
Do you mean hardware keyboard like the HTC Desire Z's keyboard?

Comment: What device are you testing on? I have a fold out device with hardware keyboard (Sidekick 4g) and when I use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` on an activity it stays in portrait when I open the keyboard. I've also tested the same thing on LG Mach, which is a slide out QWERTY also, with the same results.